# How to use special character ($) in spring application.yml or application.properties as a property key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, properties-file

While configuring a 3rd party lib in I came across the need to specify a spring property key with a special character specifically "$".

The lib wants a map which I can specify as:

```
info:
   someKeyWithDollarSign$_AfterDollarSign: someValueWithDollar$_AfterDollarSign
   otherKey: otherValue
```

But when spring reads in the properties the dollar sign ($) is gone from the key.

I put together a maven based example project [here](https://github.com/psimona/so-spring-boot-speical-charachter-as-property-key).

If you run it you will get

```
{name=123, someKeyWithDollarSign_After=someValueWithDollar$_Sign}
```

instead of the expected

```
{name=123, someKeyWithDollarSign$_After=someValueWithDollar$_Sign}
                                ^-- this would be expected
```

- Can this be at all achieved?
- Can this be achieved with property files (i.e. application.property)?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below annotation with encoding parameter into your Configuaration file:

`@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-${env}.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")`